# DeepCopy the values of an numpy array inside a for loop

Tags: arrays, numpy, copy

I have a numpy array called `initial_matrix` and inside a for-loop in each step of the loop I want to randomly change one of the indexes of that array (every time a different one) and the process my matrix.

```
init_matrix = deepcopy(my_matrix)
for i in range(0, 30):

       new_mat, rep_index = replace_index(my_matrix, value)
       ...// proceed with my process
```

The function replace_index, randomly reaplces one index of the matreix with the value. I noticed that the results of the replacement it does not occur only to `new_mat` but also to `my_matrix`. However, I want in each step of the loop to use my initial matrix and not the one after the replacement of the array. How can I do so?

Comment: And? Did my solution solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to modify your current function `(my_matrix, value)`, you can just pass a copy to this function with:

```
new_mat, rep_index = replace_index(my_matrix.copy(), value)
```

A short explanation:
This issue is generally occurring in python, **whenever you pass a mutable into a function**. **Mutables**, like `np.ndarray`, `list` or `dict` **will be passed to a function by reference**. This means all operations performed on them can be seen in the outer scope, as long as you don't rebind the reference. Rebinding operations are typically operations which change the memory address of the object, like appending, concatenating, copying, simply overwriting with a new object etc..
For an array `a = np.zeros(3)` also an operation like `a = [1., 2., 3.]` rebinds the reference (and the new type will obviously be a `list`) , while `a[:] = [1., 2., 3.]` does not, since `a[:] =` accesses the underlying memory scope for assigning the values, whereas `a = ...` does rebind the reference of `a`.

Comment: Is there any tutorial that I can dig into that issue? Why exactly the values are changing?

Comment: Yeah, there are lots of tutorials for that issue, in general here in the [Scipy Cookbook](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ViewsVsCopies.html) and the [numpy slicing and indexing documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html) or more specific on views/slicing in [numpy.ndarray.view](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html).

Comment: Oh btw.: These documentations are specifically for arrays, but this issue is occurring whenever you pass a **mutable** to a function!

Answer (score 1):

In replace_index() make a copy of my_matrix and use the copy.

Comment: Is there any tutorial that I can dig into that issue? Why exactly the values are changing?